# Facebook - Send Button/Dialog does not send Emails to single recipient, but does to more than one

Tags: facebook, email, button, dialog, send

I've run into this peculiar problem while developing a Facebook app, and I couldn't find mentions of it anywhere else.

I'm trying to use the Facebook Send Button/Dialog to send emails, but it only works for me if I specify more than one recipient's Email address.

No need to post code, it can be tested directly from the official page:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/send-button/

If I open the dialog, insert a single email address as recipient, and click on "Send", the dialog doesn't close and the email is never sent.
If I do the same thing, but insert two or more email addresses as recipients, it works like a charm, and sends the email to all.

(on a side note, if I insert a Friend as recipient, it all works fine, only email addresses cause this erratic behavior)

Does it work like that for anyone else, or is it just me?

Comment: You are right, I tried with one mail and the dialog doesn't close, try reporting a new bug here  https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/

Comment: Posted: https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/1566211906938154/

Comment: This was confirmed as a bug, originally reported on february: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/651600564898468/